# Data visualisation plugin

Tags: jquery, flash, data-visualization

I'm looking to develop something similar to this data visualisation.

http://www.driversofchange.com/docvis/slimcity/

Are there any flash or jquery plugins out there that can produce something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial graph looks like it was created using the [Flare](http://flare.prefuse.org/) AS3 library

Answer (score 1):

Try [Raphaël—JavaScript Library](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Comment: I did think about raphael, but was hoping there would be something with a bit less upfront work.